# how does a recursive factorial function know when to stop

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I was trying to write a recursive factorial function to practice my recursion and came up with this:

```
function test(num){
  return (num * test(num - 1))
}
```

However, whenever I run it, it loops forever and I get a Range Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

But if I write it to handle exceptions,

```
function factorial(num) {
    if (num < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else if (num === 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return (num * factorial(num - 1));
    }
}
```

It works perfectly.

2 questions.

1. Why doesn't the first one work?
2. How does the second one know when to stop running. If num actually was changing it's value by -1 each time it will eventually hit 0 and it should trigger the else if and return 1, but if you run factorial(3) it does return 6.

Comment: The first one always calls itself (`test()`)- it has no condition to stop. The second will stop when `num === 0`.

Comment: The second one has an `if()` statement, and doesn't recurse when it reaches the base case. This is the essence of recursion.

Comment: The second one works because even though it returns 1, that result is multiplied by `num` in the function that called it (where num = 1) and then 2 and so on up the call stack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Recursion must have a **base case** - the condition upon meeting which the function stops.
2. You are going down from `num` to `num-1` and so on until `0`, at which point the function meets the base case: `num == 0` and returns 1. From this point the recursion unwinds back, and multiplies 1*`num-(num-1)`*...*`num`.

Also, factorial is defined for non-negative integers only, so not much point in returning `-1`. Another thing: the base case should really be `num == 1`.

What you are doing is multiplying by `1` when `num ==1` and then multiplying by `1` again, when `num == 0`. <strike>Which returns wrong factorial for `factorial(0).`</strike>

**Edit**: factorial(0) is 1. So, you were indeed correct to return `1`, but I would still put it as a corner case. No need to wait that extra step to get to 0.

```
function factorial(n){
    // Handle the corner cases: you might as well just throw an error
    if (n < 0) return undefined;
    if (n == 0) return 1;

    // Base case
    if (n == 1) return 1;

    // Iterative step
    // (If the function got to this point, it means, that n > 1)
    return n * factorial(n - 1);

    // In order to return the expression on the right side of "return",
    // You need to calculate the `factorial(n - 1)`
    // When you try calculating it, you will see, that now you need to
    //     find out the `factorial(n - 1)` again, but this time the 
    //     `n` is actually `(n - 1)` :)
    // So this way, you are digging into the call stack.
    // At some point you reach the 1. WHICH RETURNS 1. WOOHOO.
    // No need to calculate the `factorial` anymore.
    // Now all the expressions you couldn't evaluate, get evaluated 1 by 1
}
```

Comment: Good description of the process of recursion. thanks. it's still hard to wrap my head around, but this is the best explanation I've seen. It sort of makes sense now. haha. I just need to use them more till they start making sense

Comment: @nwimmer123 I've updated the description a bit, I hope it's clearer.